# syscall lseek() is slower in ubuntu 2.6.32 vs 2.6.24

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu

I am running the following code on ubuntu 14 and 18. It is 6X slower on 18 on same hardware. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```c
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int fd;
        off_t m;
        time_t start, ed;
        int i, k;

        if (argc<2) exit(0);

        fd = open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
        if (fd<0) {
                printf("cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
                exit(0);
        }

        start = time(0L);
        for(k=0; k<100; ++k) {
                for(i=0;i<500000;++i) {
                        m = lseek(fd, 0, 0);
                        if (m== -1) {
                                printf("lseek failed\n");
                                exit(0);
                        }
                }
        }
        ed = time(0L);
        printf("Time: %ld\n",ed-start);
}
```

On ubuntu 14 this takes 4 seconds
On ubuntu 18 it takes 24 seconds
Hardware is same

Comment: Maybe it's extra code for _Spectre_ and _Meltdown_ prevention.

Answer (score 3):

zx485 was right. the Spectre prevention in kernel was slowing it down by a factor of 6.
Disabling the protection with the following on redhat 7 changed it to normal.

```
# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/pti_enabled
# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/retp_enabled
# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/x86/ibrs_enabled
```